# Excel VSTO addin, custom popup menu on right click using XML ribbon

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbonx

In my VSTO addin, I pop a custom menu if someone right clicks a cell containing a valid bond CUSIP (finance industry jargon for a bond id).  The method below accomplishes this using CommandBars.  The question I have is how to accomplish the same using XML ribbon definitions.
Here is the current code using command bars (works fine):

```
    private static Office.CommandBar cbBondPopup = null;
    private void Application_SheetBeforeRightClick(object Sh, Excel.Range Target, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Cancel = false; // overridden to true by btn1, btn2, btn3 handlers below (so that Excel Cell Menu is cancelled)
        if (IsBondCusip(this.Application.ActiveCell.Value2))
        {
            if (cbBondPopup == null && IsBondCusip(this.Application.ActiveCell.Value2))
            {
                // create command bar if nec
                cbBondPopup = this.Application.CommandBars.Add(Name: "BondMenu", Position: Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarPopup, Temporary: true);
                // define 3 custom buttons
                var btn1 = (Office.CommandBarButton)cbBondPopup.Controls.Add(Type: Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Temporary: true);
                var btn2 = (Office.CommandBarButton)cbBondPopup.Controls.Add(Type: Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Temporary: true);
                var btn3 = (Office.CommandBarButton)cbBondPopup.Controls.Add(Type: Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Temporary: true);
                btn1.Caption = "Bond Summary"; btn2.Caption = "Bond Details"; btn3.Caption = "Find Similar Bonds";
                // connect buttons to handlers ==> CmdBarEventHndlr(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool Cancel)
                btn1.Click += Click_BondSummary; btn2.Click += Click_BondDetails; btn3.Click += Click_FindSimilarBonds;
            }
            cbBondPopup.ShowPopup(); // pop bond menu (handlers set Cancel to true so Excel Cell Menu is cancelled unless user hits ESC)
        }
    }
```

Next, here are the same buttons defined in XLM ribbon syntax.  In this case the onAction methods have a different signature - e.g. Click_BondSummary(Office.IRibbonControl ctrl).

```
    <button id="btnBondSummary" label="BondSummary" onAction="Click_BondSummary"/>
    <button id="btnBondDetails" label="BondDetails" onAction="Click_BondDetails"/>
    <button id="btnFindBonds"   label="FindBonds"   onAction="Click_FindSimilarBonds"/>
```

I was hoping I could just put these definitions into an XML context menu and pop that.  By setting idMso="ContextMenuCell" I can cause the buttons to show up in the Excel Cell menu itself - but that's not what I want.  I want them to pop up in their own standalone popup menu.

QUESTION:  Is there a way to rewrite my right-click handler using XML ribbon button definitions instead of command bars? (Otherwise I need two definitions of everything - one for the ribbon and one for the command bar popup).

Comment: Yes, as long as it's Office 2010 or newer. The basic information can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691832(v=office.14) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-commands-to-shortcut-menus?view=vs-2017

Comment: I may be overlooking it, but I don't see any explanation of creating a custom context menu from scratch.  Lots of examples about adding custom options to existing mso context menus, but not exactly the same.